# Finding last row and last column of excel sheet in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro in excel to add Pivot Chart in one workbook. And I am trying to run that macro on another workbook.The variables ACTST and ActWB are getting the proper values. But LastRow and LastCol variables are getting the values as 0. Can anybody tell where I am wrong?

```
ACTST = ActiveSheet.Name
ActWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
 On Error Resume Next
 Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

 'Define Data Range
 LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line just hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur (you just cannot see them). If you don't see them you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work! • Remove `On Error Resume Next` and fix your errors is the solution to your issue.

Comment: When I am running the macro the same workbook it is working fine.

Comment: Did you remove `On Error Resume Next`? What happend?

Comment: Yes. I am getting Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Where? In which line? So you must fix that error.

Comment: In LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187553/discussion-between-naveen-prakash-and-p).

Comment: Specify the worksheet for `DSheet.Rows.Count` in `LastRow = DSheet.Cells(DSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thank You so much.